# How to include error bars in lmfit when fitting data to Gaussian profile?

Tags: python, lmfit

I am using lmfit to fit my data to Gaussians. There are three things I am trying to accoplish:
1) Understand how the errors are calculated in lmfit 
2) How to include my own calculated errors in lmfit
3) How to plot the errors within the fit

```
def gaussian(x, amp, cen, fwhm):
    return + amp * np.exp(-(x - cen) ** 2 / (2 * (fwhm / 2.35482) ** 2))    

def gaussian_fit(x,y,guess=[1,0,0,5],varies=[True,True,True,True]):

c = 299792458 #m/s
gmod = Model(gaussian)
gmod.nan_policy = 'omit'
#x,y - your dataset to fit, with x and y values
print (np.max(y))
gmod.set_param_hint('amp', value=guess[0],vary=varies[0])  
gmod.set_param_hint('cen', value=guess[1],vary=varies[1])
gmod.set_param_hint('fwhm', value=guess[2],vary=varies[2])  
gmod.make_params()

result = gmod.fit(y,x=x,amp=guess[0], cen=guess[1], fwhm=guess[2])

amp = result.best_values['amp']
cen = result.best_values['cen']
fwhm = result.best_values['fwhm']
#level = result.best_values['level']
sigma = fwhm / 2.35482
c = 299792458 #m/s
print(result.fit_report())

gaussfield = amp * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi * sigma ** 2)
residual = y - result.best_fit

print ('params:',amp,cen,fwhm,sigma,gaussfield)
return amp,cen,fwhm,sigma,gaussfield,residual

amp, cen, fwhm, sigma, gaussfield, residual 
= gaussian_fit(xdata,ydata,guess=[.1,6.9,.02],varies=[True,False,False])
```

I don't see where the errors are incorporated in the script, so how were they included in the final report? How can you include your own errors instead of the ones fro lmfit, and how can you finally plot these errors?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, I would recommend just using `lmfit.models.GaussianModel`, and not using `set_param_hint()` -- just be explicit, not clever -- as with:

```
from lmfit.models import GaussianModel
gmodel = GaussianModel()
params = gmodel.make_params(amplitude=1, center=0, sigma=2)
result = gmodel.fit(y, params, x=x)

print(result.fit_report())
```

Now, to your questions:

1. Uncertainties in the best-fit parameters are estimated by looking at how changing the parameter values would change the fit.  With `chi-square` defined as the sum of squares of the residual array `(data-fit)/data_uncertainty`, the uncertainties for each parameter (and the parameter-parameter correlations) are estimated as values that increase `chi-square` by 1.  There are many more in-depth resources available for how non-linear least-squares fitting works.
2. "How to include my own calculated errors in lmfit". Here, I would guess that you mean the uncertainties *in the y data*, not the uncertainties in the parameters (like how would you know the uncertainties but not the values?).  If you have uncertainties in your data, pass that in as a `weights` array to `Model.fit`, perhaps as

   result = gmodel.fit(y, params, x=x, weights=1.0/dely)
3. How to plot the errors within the fit.  You can plot the data and their errorbars with matplotlibs `errorbar` function.  If you want to plot the effect of the uncertainties in the parameters on the expected range of the best-fit curve, you can use `delmodel = result.eval_uncertainty(x=x)` and then plot `x` vs `result.best_fit + delmodel` and `result.best_fit - delmodel`.  Matplotlib's `fill_between` function is often useful for this.

Comment: Answered my questions very thoroughly and easy to understand! Thank you!

Comment: Please note, that there is also `scale_covar` parameter of `Model.fit` function. As the documentation says: "Whether to automatically scale the covariance matrix when calculating uncertainties (default is True)."